# Проверка типов данных в функции

Tags: python, tuple, typedef

Если в функцию передаётся кортеж, то посчитать длину всех его слов.
Если список, то посчитать кол-во букв и чисел в нём.
Число – кол-во нечётных цифр.
Строка – количество букв.
Сделать проверку со всеми этими случаями.

```
    `def func(a):`
        `If a== tuple():`
        `Return map(len(a.split()))`
        `If a== float():`
        `Return len(str(a))`
        `If a== str():`
        `Return len([i for i in a if  i.isalpha()])`
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: код не по правилам тут размещаете. он нечитаем.

Comment: Выражение `tuple()` создаёт пустой кортеж, а если `a` не является пустым кортежем, то значит сравнение `a==tuple()` всегда будет ложным (очевидно, непустой кортеж никогда не будет равен пустому кортежу). Аналогично и со всеми остальными проверками (`float()` создаёт число 0, `str()` создаёт пустую строку)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую использовать для проверки типов функцию isinstance(arg1, classinfo), где первый аргумент - это объект, тип которого нужно проверить, а второй это тип с которым нужно проверять(можно указывать несколько типов). И как было отмечено выше, приписывая у типа () вы вызываете их конструктор, который в свою очередь возвращает новый объект, сравнение с которым особого смысла не имеет. К тому же, использование "==" для проверки принадлежности к какому-либо типу может вызывать проблемы, хотя в вашем конкретном случае они маловероятны.